# Getting info from Wordpress DB using $wpdb and get_query_var

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been successful in doing most of what I want to do. I'm creating profile pages on an association website where staff will be able to see all of a members information on nicely formatted profile pages. I'm using the get_query_var function to query the page (http://yoursite.com/profile/?profile=1783 for example).

On the profile pages themselves I load this code first:

```
<?php  $vars = get_query_var( 'profile' ); ?>
```

And then below I run the queries. Such as:

```
 <?php $user_info = get_userdata((int) $vars); echo $user_info->last_activity . "\n"; ?>
```

(The `(int) $vars` grabs the user ID from the url.)

This is working great for user meta data, but when I try to grab data using $wpdb from other tables I'm having some trouble. For example, I'm trying to grab data from a MemberPress table on transactions. It returns data but not for the right user. For some reason it always returns values for user 756.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
<?php $status = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT status FROM wp_acfzia_mepr_transactions WHERE user_id = '(int) $vars);' "); echo $status; ?>
```

It's clearly working but not getting the "user_id" value correct. It always returns user 756. Pretty bizarre. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just $vars instead of (int) $vars);